# c regexp and negative look ahead

Tags: c, regex

I've a string such this:

`"result is abcdefg hij!klm </td"`  ( or everything else instead of abcd... )

The regex I've made is:
`"result is ([^<]+) </td"`

This works well since a result is found. But when the string is:
`"result is not found </td"`
...how can I avoid extracting the words "not found"?

I known that there is negative look-ahead expression but these don't work in regex.h in C99.

- `"(?!not found)"` -> bad regex
- `"([^n][^o][^t][^ ][^f]..)"` -> doesn't match "now", for example
- `"(([^<]+)&(!not found))"` -> bad
  regex

(there is no '&' operator, I think that a solution can be: `a&&b == !a||!b` )

--EDIT--
Here you are the part of code that compute the regex.

```
pmatch=malloc(nmatch*sizeof(regmatch_t));  

printf("regex: %s\n",patrn);

if (regcomp(&rgT,patrn,REG_EXTENDED | REG_NEWLINE) != 0)
{
    snprintf(globals.err_buff,MAX_BUFF,"bad regex: \"%s\"",patrn);
    w_report_error(globals.err_buff,__FILE__,__LINE__,__func__,0,0,error);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

-- EDIT --
maybe i found a solution:
my own regex function return the N'th backreference if passing it a number > 0 as parameter, so...
NOTE: `./regex` is only a C program that redirect argv[...] to the w_regexp of my own library.

```
$ ./regex "result is crack </td" 'result is (not found) </td|result is ([^<]+) </td' 3
regex: result is (not found) </td|result is ([^<]+) </td
"crack"
""
"result is crack </td"
$ ./regex "result is not found </td" 'result is (not found) </td|result is ([^<]+) </td' 3
regex: result is (not found) </td|result is ([^<]+) </td
""
"not found"
"result is not found </td"
```

so, i think that add a number to my struct which means the index of the backreference to use for extracting data can be a a solution, but i'll still waiting for a better way to this for another day, or 2.
thanks in advance.

--EDIT-- ( too many times :) )
it works!
i've put the string that i wanna avoid follower by '|' and the pattern for a correct string.
this is the regex:
`"result is not found </td|result is ([^<]+) </td"`
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like `"result is (?:not found)?([^<]+)</td"`?

Answer (score 0):

Aztaroth's works too `result is ((?!not found)[^<]+) </td` - difference is that his registers an empty match, mine doesn't register a match.

Tested with

```
result is abcdefg hij!klm </td
result is not found </td
result is not this </td
result is note this </td
result is ote this </td
```

**EDIT:** Shame, ok - this is lazy and bit yuck but how about two passes with a regex? The first checks for a match on 'not found' `result is (not found) </td`. Then, using your original regex for a non-match, strip out the results.

Comment: yes, i've think this, but i use this on a struct that is used tens of time ( dynamic list ) , so, your solution will add one pattern on every struct and will require to double parse tens of strings on every struct, all that's only for one particular occurrence.....I hope there is a better solution.....